# Positioning a bubble chart properly with no legend?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I took the legend out of my bubble chart using `legend: {position: 'none'}`, but it leaves an empty space at the right side of the chart

What's the best way to make the chart fill up the space on the right but still show the prices properly on the left?

I tried adjusting the `chartArea` property but it started edging the prices off the left side (i.e., they were cut off)

[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZK6Am/)

Here is a look at the chart under the inspector, you can see the empty space on the right side:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `chartArea.width` and `chartArea.left` options:

```
chartArea: {
    width: '80%',
    left: '20%'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works; it seems a bit strange that it doesn't "collapse" when the legend is removed, but needs to be manually removed...